# How to get simple, Hello World Dajaxice interaction to work?

Tags: django, dajaxice, dajax

I'm trying to get Django to produce working Ajax interactions on my web page.

I have followed the instructions for django-dajaxice here: http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html and here: http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

However, when I try to run that Ajax code in Chrome, all I get is a dialog box popped up with the word "undefined" in it

BTW, this is how I am invoking Ajax from the HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function my_js_callback(data){
        alert(data.message);
    }
</script>

AJAX!!<br/>
<br/>
<input id="myID" type="text" name="myID" maxlength="255" onclick="Dajaxice.example.sayhello(my_js_callback);"/>
<br/>
```

So why am I getting this undefined dialog box? 
I opened up Chrome's debugger and it doesn't show any errors in this case.

Incidentally, when the installation instructions above tell me to modify my urls.py, that is ambiguous. I have two urls.py; one for my site and one for my application. I put those statements in the site's url.py. But I wasn't sure if that was correct. Can someone please confirm or deny?

Comment: What are you returning from the django side?

Comment: Burhan, how can I check what is returning from the Django side?

The function in Django that is supposed to be called looks like this:


@dajaxice_register
def sayhello(request):
    return simplejson.dumps({'message':'Hello World'})

Comment: how are you running the code, using runserver? do you have debug=True?

Comment: In my settings.py, DEBUG = True.

This is how I run the Django server: python ~myUser/project_base/web_container/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80

FYI, when the onclick method above fires, I see the following line appear from the Django webserver:

"POST /dajaxice/myApp.sayhello/ HTTP/1.1"

Answer (score 4):

I was also struggling with the dajaxice example when following the installation and quickstart references you cite.  My error was similar, though I was seeing "Dajaxice.example not defined."

Let's call the main django project `myproj` and the installed app where the ajax.py file is located `myproj/myapp`.  The two parts that seemed to get it working for me were:

1. Place ajax.py file containing `def sayhello(request)` in correct directory and use the corresponding correct path for the sayhello function.

   - Place it in a directory for one of the apps listed in the settings.INSTALLED_APPS
   - If your installed app name is listed as `"myproj",` the ajax file should be `myproj/ajax.py`, the js reference should be:      `Dajaxice.myproj.sayhello(my_js_callback)`
   - If your installed app name is listed as `"myproj.subapp",` the ajax file should be `myproj/myapp/ajax.py`, the js reference should be: `Dajaxice.myproj.myapp.sayhello(my_js_callback)`  [I used this one]
   - Remember to put the `{% dajaxice_js_import %}` in the template `<head>` section

   Note: In my example, "myapp" could be replaced with "example" to match the dajaxice example code.
2. Setting up collectstatic correctly to generate a new /static/dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js file when as I updated by code.

   - I followed the directions exactly as listed in the dajaxice readthedocs installation link you referenced.
   - Added STATIC = '/static/ in the settings.py file
   - Added 'django.contrib.staticfiles' to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py file
   - ran `python manage.py collectstatic` to pull all of the files into the /static/ directory.  This includes the *generated* file `/static/dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js`
   - Inspecting this file, you should see the object hierarchy for the sayhello function as: `Dajaxice.myproj.sayhello` or `Dajaxice.myproj.myapp.sayhello`.

Also, if you are trying the multiply example from http://www.dajaxproject.com/multiply/, change `function calculate()` to match the location of your `ajax.py` file to either:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function calculate(){
        Dajaxice.myproj.myapp.multiply(Dajax.process,{'a':$('#a').val(),'b':$('#b').val()})
    };
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function calculate(){
  Dajaxice.myproj.multiply(Dajax.process,{'a':$('#a').val(),'b':$('#b').val()})
    };
</script>
```

and include the appropriate dajax js file in the `<head>` section:

```
   <script src="/static/dajax/jquery.dajax.core.js"></script>
```

or

```
  {% static "/static/dajax/jquery.dajax.core.js" %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a `POST` request, and most likely the [CSRF middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) is blocking it. Instead, send a `GET` request by modifiying the method decorator:

```
@dajaxice_register(method='GET')
def sayhello(request):
    return simplejson.dumps({'message':'Hello World'})
```

Comment: When I changed it to a GET request as you suggested, it still didn't work. Same symptom. However, this time when the onclick event fires I see this coming from the server window:

[17/Feb/2013 13:12:18] "GET /dajaxice/myApp.sayhello/?argv=undefined HTTP/1.1" 200 10567

Furthermore, I put a print statement inside sayhello(). If it reached there, it should print that line onto the server's console. But it didn't. So It's not getting to the sayhello() function.

Answer (score 0):

My error: I use debug in chrome(F12), Dajaxice is available, but **Dajaxice.example** and **Dajaxice.example.sayHello** is undifined.

you should install your APP **example** in your settings.py

http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.sites',
        'dajaxice',
        'example',
        ...
)
```

note  example/**ajax.py**, you can not put the code into other file.

cat example/**ajax.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf-8
from django.utils import simplejson
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register


@dajaxice_register()
def sayhello(request):
    return simplejson.dumps({'message':'Hello World'})
```